# Menu Icon not disappearing

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, icons, media-queries

I'm having issues with my menu icon. For my desktop css I have is set to display none. Under 1000px I have it set as display block. So far the icon is showing for all devices. Any assistance is appreciated.

```css
/* blah blah blah */

.icon-dropdown {
 display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .icon-dropdown {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   left: 80%;
   top: 50px;
 }
 .icon-dropdown div{
   display: block;
   background-color: black;
   width: 35px;
   height: 4px;
   margin-bottom: 3px; 
   position: relative;
    }




}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Vintage McDonald's</title>
 <meta id="meta" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="mcdonaldsoldlogo.png">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
 <header>
  <a href="index.html"><img src="vintagelogo.jpg" width="90px" height="90px"></a>
  <h1>Vintage McDonald's!</h1>
  <div class="icon-dropdown">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
  </div>
 </header>
 <span class="menu-trigger">Menu</span> 
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT MCDONALD'S</a></li>
   <li><a href="classics.html">OUR CLASSICS</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <div class="slideShow">
 <img class="placeHolder" src="1.jpg"> 
  <div class="layer1"></div>
  <div class="layer2"></div>
  <div class="layer3"></div>
  <div class="slideOverlay"><p>Welcome to McDonald's!<br>Come and try our NEW Big Mac!!!</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="menu.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's working. Try to click full page.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this media query:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .icon-dropdown {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      left: 80%;
      top: 50px;
    }
    .icon-dropdown div{
      display: block;
      background-color: black;
      width: 35px;
      height: 4px;
      margin-bottom: 3px;   
      position: relative;
    }

}
```

After that, try to shrink your browser to see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting width and height for the icon.